# Unity, saving lots of objects with lots of unique attributes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, save, load, xml-serialization

So I have a dilemma about how to go about saving 2000+ objects with 20 different properties each object.

I was thinking of C# serialization, but wouldn't file be too big? 
Like, I can think of it actually taking up 200mb+ of data just for the save.
Is there any other way to go about this?

Different approach would be serializing properties, but as a string. But is it right way to go, or should I not be bothered by the size of save file?

Comment: Sound like you have a database, so why not use a database instead of xml.

Comment: Well, its not a database, those are all instantiated objects, chunks to be precise, and each chunk contains some objects.

Comment: It is still a database application with the number of object in your application.  It doesn't matter that you used classes instead of a database.  You should save the data.  String take up a lot of space and it would be better to use a binary save.

Comment: you can use JSONObject too. it's pretty simple and portable. and its size should be much lesser than xml